# How to get data different website without going to the page?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, request

I retrieve data from view by jQuery and send it via ajax to the controller. In controller I get data and make get request to another website. I need to get data without going to the different website.

I'm working with the Yii2 framework.

My view (it is not a form):

```
<input id="departCity" name="departCity" type="text"> <br>
<input id="country" name="country" type="text"> <br>
<input id="date" name="date" type="date"> <br>
<input id="nights" name="nights" type="text"> <br>
<button id="findBtn" type="submit">FIND</button>
```

js file

```
 $('#findBtn').click(function(){    
        var dt = {
            'departCity': $('#departCity').val(),
            'country': $('#country').val(),
            'date': $('#date').val(),
            'nights': $('#nights').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/index.php?r=tour/partner",
            method: "get",
            data: dt,
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });
```

controller

```
public function actionPartner(){
    $data = Yii::$app->request->get();
    $uriString = 'somewebsite/searchPartner1?departCity='. $data['departCity'] . '&country=' . $data['country'] . 
    '&date=' . $data['date'] . '&nights=' . $data['nights'];
    $this->redirect($uriString, 307);
}
```

Now I can send get request to the needed website. But problem is that I don't know how to collect the data I got from website. Are there any ways to collect it without opening the page?

Comment: Is this other website your own (living within the same application), or an external website?

Comment: @paskl this is external website, nothing criminal)

Comment: I have really no idea about Yii, but it seems this should be something you are looking for: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/genxoft/curl If this is not working, you could do it with a plain curl call from your controller.

Comment: If it is possible, Im looking for solution which could be achieved with default yii. I tried the website, but I'm newbie in the composer so I couldnt set up everything properly, so I have huge amount of errors

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? post so data to that other website ? if so why dont you use `cUrl` request?